# Error operator '>' cannot be applied to 'java.lang.Integer', 'void' while check if in Spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot

I've a method in my **java-spring boot** application.

```
public OrderDTO save(OrderDTO orderDTO) {
    log.debug("Request to save Order : {}", orderDTO);
    Optional<Product> purchased = productRepository.findById(orderDTO.getProduct());
    Order order = OrderMapper.INSTANCE.toEntity(orderDTO);
    Objects.requireNonNull(purchased.get(), "You cannot buy a non existing product");

    order.setProduct(purchased.get());
    
    purchased.get().setStock(purchased.get().getStock() - order.getQuantity());

    order = orderRepository.save(order);
    productRepository.save(purchased.get());
    return OrderMapper.INSTANCE.toDto(order);
}
```

The *order.quantity* can't less than *purchase.stock*. So I need to make condition to check that and send errorMessage if the *order.quantity* less than *purchase.stock*

If tried

```
if(order.getQuantity() > purchased.get().setStock(purchased.get().getStock())){
        log.debug("Quantity must less than Product stock");
}
```

but show error **operator '>' cannot be applied to 'java.lang.Integer', 'void'**

#### How do I can fix this to do check?

Comment: `setStock` is probably void. So you can't use `>` with that

Comment: setStock is a void method. It doesn't return anything. You are trying to compare a number with nothing.

Comment: Setters generally dont return a value, did you mean to put the value into a local variable and compare that?

Comment: @ernest_k yah you're right. My failure, thankyou :D

Answer (score 0):

You're comparing the result of the `getQuantity` method (an Integer) to the result of `setStock`, a void method that doesn't return anything.

You likely want the following:

```
if(order.getQuantity() > purchased.get().getStock()) {
    log.debug("Quantity must less than Product stock");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

setters generally return void, so you can try

```
if(order.getQuantity() > purchased.get().getStock()){
    log.debug("Quantity must less than Product stock");
} else {
    purchased.get().setStock(purchased.get().getStock());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Integer stock=purchased.get().getStock();
if(order.getQuantity() > stock) {
   log.debug("Quantity must less than Product stock");
} else {
    // Here you pack the order and add into custpmer account and save remaing stock.
    purchased.get().setStock(stock-order.getQuantity());
}
```